# In what order are application.yml read in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, application.properties

I  suppose that it reads in work **working circuit** and then it reads in **testing circuit**.

If **application.yml** is in **testing circuit** , it settings replace the settings has been reading in **application.yml**  of  **working circuit.** If You have defined **application-test.yml** and you point above a class an annotation **@SpringBootTest** and above **@ActiveProfile("test")** then the settings from **application-test.yml** replaces earlier settings.

what do you think about all this ? How to understand this process correctly?

Comment: What is `contour` ? Anyway, maybe read this: https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring

Comment: a contour is a logical area of the project where the application or tests are located. These are 2 different places in the context of the project. For link that you have pointed, there is little info: ..."4.3. Test-Specific Properties File
We might also have a requirement to use different property values when our application is under test.

Spring Boot handles this for us by looking in our src/test/resources directory during a test run. Again, default properties will still be injectable as normal but will be overridden by these if there is a collision." - I'm not sure I got it right.

Answer (score 1):

- Terminology:

**Work Circuit** : /src/main/resources

**Test Circuit** : /src/test/resources

- Work Circut

application.yaml

```yaml
main:
  car:
    name: "Audi"
    id: "10201"
```

application-local.yaml

```yaml
main:
  car:
    name: "Mercedes"
    id: "10200"
```

- main class

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringProfilesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringProfilesApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ProfileMain profileMain) {
        return args -> {
            profileMain.printMainName();

        };
    }
}
```

- class

```java
@Component
public class ProfileMain {

    @Value("${main.car.name}")
    private String name;

    @Value("${main.car.id}")
    private String id;

    public void printMainName() {
        System.out.println("\n name in Main application.yaml : " + this.name + "\n");
        System.out.println("\n name in Main application.yaml : " + this.id + "\n");
    }
}
```

– When you run the main class, without specifying any profiles, **application.yaml** will be used.
– You can specify the profile you need in the **development environment**

[image]

Now the settings of those properties that were in the main **application.yaml**, will be overridden in the specified profile - **local**.
If the selected profile does not contain the settings that are in the main **application.yaml**, then the missing properties will be taken from the main **application.yaml**.

- Test circuit

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = SpringProfilesApplication.class)
class ProfileMainTest {

    @Value("${main.car.name}")
    private String name;

    @Value("${main.car.id}")
    private String id;

    @Test
    void printMainName() {
        System.out.println("\n In test circuit : " + name);
        System.out.println("\n In test circuit : " + id);
    }
```

When we do not explicitly specify a profile, the settings will be taken from the main **application.yaml**.

Now we use the ***.yaml** file from the test loop.

**application-test.yaml**

```java
main:
  car:
    name: "Nissan"
    id: "10203"
```

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = SpringProfilesApplication.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class ProfileMainTest {
...
}
```

Here the properties (if any) will be redefined, that is, taken from the **application-test.yaml** file.
But if there is no property, then it will be taken from the main file
**application.yml**.

- Resume

**In the Working circuit**

1. If the profile is not specified, the settings will be taken from the main **application.yaml**.
2. If a profile is specified, then the settings from this profile will override the settings from the main **application.yaml** file.
   If some settings are missing, then the settings will be taken from the main **application.yaml** file(if any).

**In the test circuit**

1. If the profile is not specified, the settings will be taken from the main **application.yaml**.
2. If a profile is specified, then the settings from this profile will override the settings from the main **application.yaml** file.
   If some settings are missing, then the settings will be taken from the main **application.yaml** file (if any).

Answer (score 0):

According to [Spring Boot reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config), the configuration data files are considered in the following order:

1. Application properties packaged inside your jar (application.properties and YAML variants).
2. Profile-specific application properties packaged inside your jar (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants).
3. Application properties outside of your packaged jar (application.properties and YAML variants).
4. Profile-specific application properties outside of your packaged jar (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants).

Answer (score -1):

you have to put this in your **application-test.yml**

```
spring:
  profiles: test
```